# How to create a copy of a Google Docs template with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have a Google docs template document in a Google Drive file that I would like to duplicate so that it fits in another folder in my Google Drive while including variable field replacement.
My problem is that my .makeCopy function is not working.I want this function copy a template model on Google Sheet, replaces variables fields.
And I am getting this type of comment on my execution log

[image]

Here is the script I am using.
Would you have a solution to solve this problem?

```
function createPDF(){

 const info = {
  'Nom': ['Jane'],
  'Prénom': ['Marcus'],
  'Nom de l’entreprise': ['Doe'],
  'Adresse': ['123 Avenue Morne-à-lo']
 };

 
 const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1S0cWh_hXl-VtyxkrJEOdPcxeiR8Yakkh');
 const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1dYMbvwVCexrcQJKVuLcnaDpT2Ipjy8WA');
 const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFolderById('1xmDYuQyqGCVCSQVWzdckBJUOdqjarhdKhEdfdMnh1og');

 const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

 const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
 const body = openDoc.getBody();
 body.replaceText("{Nom}". info["Nom"][0]);
 body.replaceText("{Prénom}". info["Prénom"][0]);
 body.replaceText("{Nom de l'entreprise}". info["Nom de l'entreprise"][0]);
 body.replaceText("{Adresse}". info["Adresse"][0]);
 openDoc.saveAndClose();

 const blobPDF= newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
 const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF). setName("My PDF");

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The referred comment was not included. Please assure that the code included in the questions is a [mcve] (it doesn't make sense to include `myFunction` as it doesn't do anything other than taking space).

Comment: Please add error messages as text no as images

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the error is caused by a mistake made few lines above as `1xmDYuQyqGCVCSQVWzdckBJUOdqjarhdKhEdfdMnh1og` looks to be too long for a folder id (update: actually it's a document id)

try replacing

```
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFolderById('1xmDYuQyqGCVCSQVWzdckBJUOdqjarhdKhEdfdMnh1og');
```

by

```
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('1xmDYuQyqGCVCSQVWzdckBJUOdqjarhdKhEdfdMnh1og');
```